Cannot import enviroment variables in Nextjs
I am using nextjs 15 and I cannot import the env variables (which is a database url), with typescript. I tried different methods like:
import { loadEnvConfig } from "@next/env";
const projectDir = process.cwd();
loadEnvConfig(projectDir);

and Tried to import it in the files in which I wannted to use the env variable, to test it I just made a react page in which if I press a button it will log the database url, but the result always came out to be undefined. I even tried to use a env.d.ts file with this given code:
namespace global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface processEnv {
      DATABASE_URL: string;
    }
  }
}

With no result, or even just used dotenv like this:
import { config } from "dotenv";
config({ path: ".env" });

export const testEnv = (): void => {
  console.log("DATABASE_URL:", process.env.DATABASE_URL);
};

just to even show u this is the page in the /src/test/page.tsx:
"use client";
import { testEnv } from "../../db";

export default function Page() {
  const handleClick = () => {
    testEnv();
  };

  return (
    <div className="p-4">
      <input
        type="button"
        value="Test Environment"
        onClick={handleClick}
        className="px-4 py-2 bg-blue-500 text-white rounded cursor-pointer hover:bg-blue-600"
      />
    </div>
  );
}

